# Sql query for merge two rows into one row if id is same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table named TICKET_LAB 
    I have table named TICKET_LAB 
as shown
    as shown
[TICKET_LAB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edScJ.png)

[image]

and table named test 
    and table named test 
as shown
    as shown
[Test table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEJtc.png)

[image]

I need a SQL query to get the result like that :

I need a SQL query to get the result like that :

```
TLAB_TICKETID | TEST_NAME
------------- | -------------
    29        | blood, stool,...etc
```

any idea

Comment: Please copy the table structure instead of incapsulate them in the images

Comment: sql-server or mysql?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tckt.TLAB_TICKETID, STUFF(
     (SELECT ',' + TEST_NAME 
      FROM [hos].[dbo].[test]
      WHERE tckt.TLAB_TESTID = Test_ID
      FOR XML PATH (''))
     , 1, 1, '')
FROM [hos].[dbo].[test] tst
    JOIN [hos].[dbo].[Ticket_Lab] tckt
    on tst.Test_ID = tckt.TLAB_TESTID
GROUP BY tckt.TLAB_TICKETID
```

I think this should work.

Comment: I believe the guy is looking for `GROUP_CONCAT` solution

Comment: thank for your help but as @mitkosoft said i need it grouped by the TLAB_TICKETID

Comment: There is no GROUP_CONCAT function in SQL Server.

Comment: @DenisReznik He has MySQL in the tags too. So until he clarifies then who knows!!

Comment: As far I can see from attached images, we are talking about SQL Server, but not MySQL.

Comment: error when execute the query "Column 'hos.dbo.Ticket_Lab.TLAB_TESTID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server it may looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TICKET_LAB(Id int)
INSERT INTO #TICKET_LAB VALUES(1), (2)

CREATE TABLE #TEST(TicketId int, Name nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES(1, 'blood'), (1, 'etc.'), (2, 'test')

SELECT Id, STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + t.Name FROM #TEST t WHERE tl.Id = t.TicketId FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''
    )
FROM #TICKET_LAB tl
```